# Find point C that forms perpendicular line BC to line AB

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, geometry, 2d

I have Line segment `AB` defined by two **2D** points `A,B`.

What I am trying to do is find a point `C`, with distance `d` away from `B`.
The two constraints are that `BC` has to be perpendicular to `AB`  and  `BC` is always `90` degrees anti-clockwise relative to `AB`.

So far I have the following

```
double d = .01;
Coordinate C = new Coordinate(A.Lat - B.Lat, A.Long - B.Long);

C.Long = C.Long * A.Long * Math.Cos(90);
C.Lat = C.Lat * A.Lat * Math.Cos(90);

C.Long = A.Long + C.Long * d;
C.Lat = A.Lat + C.Lat * d;
```

Essentially what I am asking is, where am I going wrong with this? Is it the c# code? Is it the logic? What are the steps to solve for `C` using those two constraints.

[image]

Comment: Where exactly is the problem, is it with the programming in C# part or the geometry/math underneath?

Comment: It's in the Geometry/math. I don't think i have it correct

Comment: Note: That was a hint to remove the C# part and the C# tag. I don't see any geo/math at all, apart from what you have coded there, for which there isn't even a description that relates the code to the graphic. BTW: One quick bug in your code is that typically, angles are not represented in degrees but radians.

Comment: That could 100% be it! let me check

Comment: actually there is no need to calculate cosinus of 90° - it is a well known constant... that is ZERO and multiplication by zero results in zero - so there seems to be an error in the formula since at the end C will have the same coordinates as A

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger you are right, but also notice `Math.Cos()` requires the angle in radians, probably the OP meant `Math.Cos(90 * (Math.PI/180))`

Comment: @bto.rdz sure, I am supposing he meant that and that obvioulsy is also ZERO. (90° == 90*PI/180)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yes, it, just pointing another mistake, just the OP might be confused because we wont see the ZERO you told him.

Comment: @bto.rdz changed my comment so it shold be clear that the problem is the formula and not (only) coding

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I added the c# tag to let users know what language I'm doing this in, in case i'm doing something wrong in the c# language.

Comment: @KelseyAbreu I reedit your question to make more sense from math side (point can not be perpendicular to anything).  What is your coordinate system ? (which way which axis points and if you use angles also which way the angle rise and where is its zero)

Answer (score 6):

Normalize AB vector and rotate it by 90 degrees:

```
ABY = B.Y - A.Y
ABX = B.X - A.X
Len = Sqrt(ABY*ABY + ABX*ABX)
C.X = B.X - d * ABY / Len 
C.Y = B.Y + d * ABX / Len
```

Note that for geographic coordinates (Lat/Long) and large distances result is not exact.

[Link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) for further reference (sections `Bearing` then `Destination point given distance and bearing from start point`)

Comment: I think you are forgetting about the constraint that C must always be on the left of B.

Comment: @KelseyAbreu and how would you know his code does not already achieve this, when your *own* terminology is inconsistent? In the first diagram, C is clearly on the right of B. What the two diagrams show is that BC is always 90 degrees anti-clockwise relative to AB.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog very true, i didn't really know how to describe that. I will fix that

Comment: @Kelsey Abreu You can exchange `+/-` signs in the last pair of formulas if `left` is inconsistent with your coordinate system (it depends). I consider `left` term as path A-B-C makes left turn after B.

Comment: @KelseyAbreu it Also depends on the coordinate system which way the x,y axises points (or long,lat ...)

Answer (score 1):

**MBo** has the correct answer for your task (as you got 90 degrees turn) I just wanted to show you how to repair your own code (I deduced you wanted to do this) which is usable to any angular turn (but slower as it require goniometric):

```
d = .01;
a = atan2(B.y - A.y,B.x - A.x) (+/-) 90.0; // sign depends on your coordinate system
C.x = B.x + d*cos(a)
C.y = B.y + d*sin(a)
```

So you should obtain directional angle `a` of your `AB` and shift it by 90 deg. Then you just add `d` rotated by the `a` to the `C` which can be done by parametric circle equation.

Beware all the angles should be in units your goniometric functions accepts (so either degrees or radians) as I do not code in **C#** I have not a clue but in languages I code in it is usually in radians. In which case line:

```
a = atan2(B.y - A.y,B.x - A.x) (+/-) 90.0; // sign depends on your
```

Would change to:

```
a = atan2(B.y - A.y,B.x - A.x) (+/-) 90.0*Pi/180.0; // sign depends on your
```

Where `Pi=3.1415926535897932384626433832795`.